# Redirect to a subpage if user was forwarded

Tags: php, dns

The DNS records of website A are forwarding the user to website B. What I want to do is: When the user is coming from website A, he should get redirected to a **subpage** of website B. How can I do this?

Comment: you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])) { // check if $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] is there or not
    if ($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] == 'http://www.example.com/') { // match for domain name
        header("Location:http://www.yourBsite.com"); //redirect where you want
    }
}
```

Place this code on `index.php` or on the file which is calling first.

Comment: Thank you, would that also work if the url was http://www.example.com/something?v=whatever ?

Comment: `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`  always take the url from where site refereed. So it will work.

Comment: I have changed `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` to `parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST)`. It works fine and shows me only the domain. That's all I need. Thanks!